# If temperature is not defined in softmax, does it mean temperature is 1?

Tags: softmax

I could not find this answer anywhere. How does one find implicit temperature in a softmax implementation? It seems like the answer should exist somewhere (could be so obvious, in which case I apologize). I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes. PyTorch's softmax (from nn module) doesn't even allow for temperature, so these tags don't make much sense.

Comment: @Berriel Thank you. So implicit temperature is always 1 unless specified, correct?

Comment: @superbot yes. If you want temperature you just divide the input tensor to softmax by T

Answer (score -1):

It's quite simple.

If the output values of the final layer are called 'logits', you can use the following function to apply temperature scaling to the softmax calculation:

```
def temperature_scaled_softmax(logits, temperature=1.0):
    logits = logits / temperature
    return torch.softmax(logits, dim=0)
```

Then, you can use this function to compute softmax with different temperature values:

```
t1_probs = temperature_scaled_softmax(logits, temperature=10)
t2_probs = temperature_scaled_softmax(logits, temperature=0.1)
```

If the temperature is set to 1, the results will be the same as using nn.Softmax().